# Trying to allow the scroll wheel to control final flash animation. I'd Love some assistance with this AS3 snippet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scroll

I'm working in Flash CC and trying to get the scrollwheel to control which direction and at what speed the animation is played. Here is what I have so far:

```
function handleMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void {
trace("The delta value is: " + event.delta);
var frame:int = (currentFrame + event.delta);
gotoAndStop(frame); 

}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
```

I haven't used Flash very much and I was told that I need to assign the name "clip_mc" to the object on the stage via the Properties panel, and I'm not exactly sure what that means. (especially since this piece of code affects the entire file and not just a single object)

Although, I'm not getting any errors, my animation is just playing normally and is not affected by the scroll wheel.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to create a movieclip with your animation inside it
then drag that moviclip to the stage
give it a instance name like myAnim  (in the top right corner of flash properties panel while the movieclip is selected)

then in the code type myAnim.stop();
to make sure when you start the swf animation will be paused, which is why your anim keeps just playing as default

then add your event listener
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);

then in the handleMouseWheel you can then reference the movieclip  and control it like
myAnim.gotoAndStop(frame);

hope this helps

Comment: Cool idea, I've got the movieclip on the stage and gave it an instance name "myAnim". Mind taking a look at my code so far?  http://imgur.com/jg1XT5W  I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is. No errors though!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the add event listener from inside `handlemousewheel()` and where you say `currentFrame` you are referencing the current frame of the main timeline not `myAnim`. To do that you would have to say `myAnim.currentframe = event.delta`.

You need to make sure the `event.delta` corresponds to the frames you have and you may want to encapsulate it within a `math.clamp` to make sure it doesn't go too far.